# om ClojureScript ref-cursor error when trying to update vector using om/transact

Tags: clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, cursors, om

I am seeing the following error when trying to update a cursor:

```js
Uncaught Error: No protocol method ITransact.-transact! defined for type function: function comments(){return om.core.ref_cursor.call(null,new cljs.core.Keyword(null,"comments-data","comments-data",1871210833).cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$1(om.core.root_cursor.call(null,cljs_playground.core.app_state)));
```

I am using a ref-cursor to point to the comments-data vector in my application state:

```js
(def app-state
  (atom
    {:comments-data [{ :author "Commenter 1" :text "comment 1" }
                     { :author "Commenter 2" :text "comment 2" }]}))

(defn comments []
  (om/ref-cursor (:comments-data (om/root-cursor app-state))))
```

Now, I would like to update this cursor when a user submits some data via an input in my input component. I use (let [foo (->> comments)] to refer to the cursor inside render-state. I pass it into a function call that handles the user submit and I would like to simply add one more item to this vector.

```js
(defn handle-submit [e owner {:keys [text]} foo]
  (om/transact! foo #(concat % {:author "foo" :text "bar"}))
  (om/set-state! owner :text ""))

(defn Input
  [data owner]
  (reify
    om/IInitState
    (init-state [_]
      {:text nil})
    om/IRenderState
    (render-state [this state]
     (let [foo (->> comments)]
       (dom/div nil
         (dom/input #js
           { :type "text"
             :ref "text-field"
             :value (:text state)
             :onChange (fn [event] (handle-change event owner state))})
         (dom/button #js 
           { :onClick (fn [event] (handle-submit event owner state foo))} "submit"))))))
```

However, when I make the om/transact! call I am seeing the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call your `comments` function and use its return value (the cursor), not use the function itself. Change this line:

```
 (let [foo (->> comments)]
```

to:

```
 (let [foo (->> (comments))]
```

and that should work for you.

Comment: Hi @rmunn, first of all thank you. Second, I made the changes you suggested. I refreshed the page but now I see that none of my content is showing on the page. I don't see any error out put from the compiler but I do see Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined in my console. I created an updated gist which contains all the code for this demo I am doing. I think this is the right track, just not sure why it's not displaying properly. https://gist.github.com/mjw56/25e126f45a29ee58f313

Comment: @user16626 - I'd suggest asking this as a separate question on Stack Overflow, as it seems to be a different problem. But my guess is that the `(om/build Input ((get global :comments-data) this)))` line near the end is wrong. First, you have the wrong parentheses -- you're getting the :comments-data key, then *calling* it with `this` as a parameter? Almost certainly not what you meant to do. Second, there is no `this` defined anywhere in your `my-app`.

Comment: @user16626 - I'm about to be away from the Internet for several days. If you have more problems with this code, you should turn [the gist you posted](https://gist.github.com/mjw56/25e126f45a29ee58f313) into another question, so that others can help you with your problems. Because if you write me anything more, I won't see it until about Friday the 12th.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
(let [foo (->> comments)]
```

to

```
(let [foo (comments)]
```

and keep it simpler. There is no need for the `->>` operator.